# Accept or reject unsolicited icmpv6 from internet

Tags: networking, ipv6

I tested my router rig with a few ipv6 test sites.
I'm getting 10/10 for most.
However, for http://ipv6-test.com, I get 18/20 (screen cap below).

It basically says I should allow workstation to be reachable by ICMP v6 coming from internet.

Should unsolicited ICMP v6 from internet be routed to workstations?

I make the distinction with "sollicited" ICMPv6, for example when ping -6 commands receive answers from e.g. stackoverflow.com

[image]

Comment: IPv6 needs ICMP for a lot of things. For example, IPv4 can fragment packets along the path, but IPv6 cannot, and it uses ICMP for PMTUD. IPv6 needs to discover the smallest MTU in the path so that it can adjust the MTU on the packets before sending. In general, there is nothing wrong with allowing ICMPv6. This is one of those things where you need to get out of IPv4 thinking, and into IPv6 thinking.

Comment: I'm allowing RELATED packets with the net filter connection tracking mechanism. This should allow ICMPv6 "errors" to come back for TCP or UDP traffic originating from the workstation. In this case ICMPv6 is "expected" by the stateful firewall. However, completely random ICMPv6 echo from internet would be blocked.

Comment: But, you are not allowing a host sending something to you, e.g. web server, to determine the path MTU. That was only an example. IPv6 heavily depends on ICMP in ways that IPv4 doesn't. You need to forget the IPv4 thinking, and get into IPv6 thinking.

Comment: Which ICMPv6 packet types would the web server sends to determine MTU? FWIW, I understand that ICMPv6 must be accepted from the WAN port link local address, so that neighbour discovery, and router advertisement ICMPv6 packets are received. Else internet routing is broken!

Comment: I will try this once again. IPv6 uses ICMP in ways that IPv4 does not, and it heavily depends on that. You should, in general allow ICMPv6. You really need to drop the IPv4 thinking with IPv6. _RFC 4443, Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMPv6) for the Internet Protocol Version 6 (IPv6) Specification_ says it best: "_ICMPv6 is an integral part of IPv6, and the base protocol (all the messages and behavior required by this specification) MUST be fully implemented by every IPv6 node._"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quite a bit of research, the following RFC quite nails it:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4890#section-4.3

TLDR; the following ICMPv6 packet types mustn't be dropped from a global link address:

- Destination Unreachable (Type 1)
- All codes Packet Too Big (Type 2)
- Time Exceeded (Type 3) Code 0 only
- Parameter Problem (Type 4) Codes 1 and 2 only
- Echo Request (Type 128)
- Echo Response (Type 129)